# How to have Function "FirstNumeric" be run only once?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently writing a program in Excel using VBA that takes contract numbers (Alphanumeric string) that consists of three parts:

Office - Two or three alpha characters at the beginning of a string (upper or Lowercase)

Example: "abc"

Base - four or five numbers in the middle of the string

Example: "12345"

Comparative - A single Alpha character at the end of the string (not all strings will have this)

Example: "E"

Example of Contract Number: "abc12345E

I have a column of these contract numbers in column E in a spreadsheet and I have written code to separate the "Office" portion in column F, "Base" in column G, and "Comparative" in column H.

My issue is that I have a function called "FirstNumeric" that is used to find where in the string my numeric characters start so it can be separated at those points. But I only want to call this function once. In my code, I call it twice. How can I write this code so that the function is called only once?

```
 Public Sub PharseContractNumber()
    Dim MyContract As String
    Dim MyIndex As Integer

    'Set Index to first process row
    MyIndex = 3

    'Get First Contract
    MyContract = UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & MyIndex)))  'Tells which column the original strings are in, so they can be transformed

    'Stop if no contract
    Do Until MyContract = ""

            'Write Office
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & MyIndex) = UCase(Mid(MyContract, 1, (FirstNumeric(MyContract) - 1)))

            'Remove Office
            MyContract = Mid(MyContract, (FirstNumeric(MyContract)))

            'Check for Trailing Alpha Character
            If Not (IsNumeric(Mid(MyContract, Len(MyContract)))) Then

                'Write Comparative
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & MyIndex) = UCase(Mid(MyContract, (Len(MyContract))))

                'Remove Comparative
                MyContract = Mid(MyContract, 1, Len(MyContract) - 1)   'removes the Comparative portion of the original string in the Base Column

            End If

            'Write Remaining ... Base number
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & MyIndex) = UCase(MyContract) 'writes in the base number

        'Advance Index
        MyIndex = MyIndex + 1

        'Get Next Contract
        MyContract = Trim(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & MyIndex))
    Loop

    End Sub

    Private Function FirstNumeric(PassContract) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    FirstNumeric = 0

    For i = 1 To Len(PassContract) + 1
        If IsNumeric(Mid(PassContract, i, 1)) Then
            FirstNumeric = i
            Exit For

        End If
    Next

    End Function
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the question, but is there a reason you can't store the value of calling `FirstNumeric` into a variable, then just reference the variable?

Comment: There was nothing preventing me from doing so, my brain was fried at the time. Sometimes the most simple of answers slip away from us haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold it in a variable which you load to once, but refer to twice. - Like so:

```
Dim FirNum As Integer

'Stop if no contract
Do Until MyContract = ""

        FirNum = FirstNumeric(MyContract)

        'Write Office
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & MyIndex) = UCase(Mid(MyContract, 1, (FirNum - 1)))

        'Remove Office
        MyContract = Mid(MyContract, FirNum)
```